# Not applicable to expression type error?

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

I've posted this question already but I've went back and changed my code a lot. I'm getting a new error which I don't understand. I went in for help but the TA's don't understand it as well. It is giving me an error on my .get method inside the for loop. I've tried looking it up on the java API and found a .values. I tried that but still it didn't work. The error says specifically not applicable to expression type It says required array or java.lang.Iterable but found String.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

// N O   C O M M A N D  L I N E   A R G S!
// A L L   F I L E N A M E S  M U S T  B E  H A R D C O D E D

public class Pacs
{
public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception
{
        BufferedReader pacsFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "pacs.txt" ) );
        BufferedReader membersFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "members.txt" ) );
        TreeMap<String,String> Map = new TreeMap<String,String>();
        ArrayList<String> acroymn = new ArrayList<String>();
        String group;
        String people;
        while((group = pacsFile.readLine()) != null)
        {
            acroymn.add(group);
        }
        Collections.sort(acroymn);
        pacsFile.close();
        while((membersFile.ready()))
        {
            ArrayList<String> members = new ArrayList<String>();
            people = membersFile.readLine();
            String [] peoples = people.split(" ");
            members.add(peoples[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i< peoples.length; i++)
            {

                Map.put(peoples[i],peoples[0]);
            }

        }
        membersFile.close();

        for(String acro: acroymn)
        {
            String name = "";
            for(String mem: Map.keySet())
            {
                for(String S: Map.get())
                {
                    if(acro.equals(S))
                    {
                        name = name+ " " + mem;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(acro + " " + name);      


        }


} // END MAIN

} // CLASS
```

Comment: Google how to iterate over a Map. Your syntax is a tad off.

Comment: The error says specifically not applicable to expression type It says required array or java.lang.Iterable but found String. This is for the .get() method in the for loop

Comment: Java has an interface named `Map`.  If you use a variable named `Map`, with the same letter case and everything, you will confuse the *#&$*&# out of everybody.  No wonder your TA's couldn't understand it.  Change it to `map` and it will be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It is problematic for several reasons to have a variable name like "Map" but that aside, the code you pasted there calls "Map.get()" where "Map" is a reference to an instance of TreeMap.  There is no get() method in TreeMap which accepts no arguments so I don't expect that the code above even compiles.

Comment: Yea, it doesn't compile. I look up treemap java api and .get() is a method?

Comment: Sorry. It should be Map.get(mem). Thats whats giving me the error. I do have an argument

Answer (score 0):

The code is screwy enough that it is difficult say what you are trying to accomplish.  Is it the case that instead of this (which won't even compile)...

```
for(String S: Map.get(mem))
{
    if(acro.equals(S))
    {
        name = name+ " " + mem;
    }
}
```

Are you looking for something like this?...

```
String s = Map.get(mem);
if(acro.equals(s))
{
    name = name+ " " + mem;
}
```